Can't get the wavy texture to be straight
I'm trying to make grooves on my jar lid, but the lines aren't staying straight. They're curving into an arch at the end. Can someone help me fix this? I've looked everywhere for answers.


That's totally normal behaviour.
The solution for this is UV Editing:

I just added here a simply cylinder to make it clear.
The wave texture is set to Bands/x, so Blender calculates the wave according to the x coordinate. Knowing that and using your math knowledge you recognize, that Blender does this perfectly right.
So how can you change that?
You can change the x-coordinates, if you are using UV coordinates in your texture coordinate node instead of generated coordinates.
These x-coordinates (1) you can influence by uv-editing.
So make sure that your vertical faces (2) are mapping in even faces in uv editing (1). Then use the uv coordinates (3) in shader nodes and everything works as expected.


thanks!!! didn't know it was so simple. Flew didn't notice this

glad if i can help

@Henry .. don't forget to upvote, too, if you think this is a good one :)

thanks, will do!
